# Google Spreadsheet to Normal Form (or vice versa?)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I automatically change a Google Spreadsheet table in the shown way below?

I need some columns spread to rows with their values, so the rows have to be also multiplied automatically.

In the end of the day, the real table has much more rows...

---

Before:

| MONTH | MONTH_NAME | IST | BUDGET | EL | FL | MAT | SONSTIGES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | January | 132,898.62 | 250,000 | 15,000 | 0 | 555,000 | 1,215.35 |
| 1 | January | 0 | 215000 | 0 | 0 | 285000 | 0 |

After:

| MONTH | MONTH_NAME | IST | BUDGET | BUDGET_CLUSTER | CLUSTER_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | January | 0.00 | 215,000 | EL | 0 |
| 1 | January | 0.00 | 215,000 | FL | 0 |
| 1 | January | 0.00 | 215,000 | MAT | 285,000 |
| 1 | January | 0.00 | 215,000 | SONSTIGES | 0 |
| 1 | January | 132,898.62 | 250,000 | EL | 15,000 |
| 1 | January | 132,898.62 | 250,000 | FL | 0 |
| 1 | January | 132,898.62 | 250,000 | MAT | 555,000 |
| 1 | January | 132,898.62 | 250,000 | SONSTIGES | 1,215 |

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,{"","","","","",""},
    query(
          reduce(Σ,sequence(counta(A2:A)),lambda(a,c,{a;
          reduce(Σ,sequence(counta(E1:H1)),lambda(x,y,{x;index(A2:D,c),index(E1:H1,,y),index(E2:H,c,y)}))})),
   "where Col1 is not null",))
```

[image]